# php_flag in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I run an apache-server and I need just one php_flag to differ from the global configuration in a virtual host.

I did not have a .htaccess file in that virtual hosts directory, so I just added it containing

```
php_flag flagname On
```

My httpd.conf contains

```
<Directory "/path/to/host">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

and I use the standard server API, not suPHP or anything

Anyway, phpinfo keeps telling me that the flag I set to On was still Off.
The flag is suhosin.simulation, that one should be able to be set in .htaccess.

What am I missing?

Comment: Which flag? You cannot override any php setting in `.htaccess`.

Comment: php_flag takes effect when php running as an apache module.Do you?

Comment: I know this may seem obvious, but have you tried restarting Apache? I've noticed that php_flag/php_values set in .htaccess have no effect until Apache is restarted.

Comment: I did restart the apache. Also if I make obvious mistakes in that .htaccess file it gives me errors, so it's being read.

Comment: Was PHP loaded as an Apache module or FCGI? Those directives are only valid in `.htaccess` when PHP is an Apache module, not FCGI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`php_flag` can only set **PHP_INI_ALL** and **PHP_INI_PERDIR** type directives.  You may need to use a `php_admin_flag` within a `<Directory xxxxxxxxxx>` `</Directory>` scope in your vhost config.  You will need to restart Apache to latch this.