# Disallow running php file

Tags: php, apache

I have this directory tree:

```
dir/
    file.php
   .htaccess
```

In `.htaccess` I have:  `php_flag engine off`, so if the file `dir/file.php`, is called directly, it won't run.

But if I include `file.php` in other php files, outside of this directory, `file.php` runs anyway.

Is it possible to prevent all php files from running within the directory, even if they are included from other files outside this directory ?

Comment: If you don't want to run it why is the file there?

Comment: Try to change your permissions to disallow www-data to access this folder.

Comment: @Raphaël Malié pretty sure thats gonna be the answer.

Comment: @RaphaëlMalié Though keep in mind you have no idea what OS OTARIKI is running, so `www-data` may not be the actual username involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn PHP processing off in `.htaccess`. That has to be done on the Apache config level

```
<Directory /your/path/here>
    php_admin_flag engine off
</Directory>
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the asker's issue with `include()`ing a file in that directory from somewhere else and having the code run; you're not actually answering the asker's question.

Comment: "You can't turn PHP processing off in .htaccess. That has to be done on the Apache config level"
That's a total contradiction you have here ! .htaccess are meant to configure apache

Comment: @Sekai You're confusing two things here. `.htaccess` is NOT the same thing as a config file. It can do many config level things but it cannot do them all. While you can specify which files PHP will process, if you want to turn PHP processing off for an entire directory this is the only way. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537965/php-flag-in-htaccess) for more detail.

Comment: @Crontab You're right in that he's trying to include a PHP file, not execute it directly, but this is the closest I think you can get with any server level configs. Unfortunately, when you include a PHP file, it becomes part of the calling file as far as PHP is concerned.

Comment: @Machavity *I* know that, but the asker appears to be unfamiliar with the idea.  The only way to truly do what the asker wants is with permissions and/or ACLs, denying access to the directory in question for the web server user.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a little extra logic into the php files in that directory:

```
 if($the-Criteria-Which-Keeps-You-From-Deleting-The-Files-Is-Met){ 

    // Your otherwise not-allowed code runs here

     } 
//Thus, the contents of this script do not execute unless you want them to.
```

Now, I have a few of these, myself, and the logic I use in the above `if()` statement goes like this:

`if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $my-Development-IP) { [...]`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do this to prevent any upload for php files, 

this is what I use for my website:

```
 AddType text/plain .php .php3 .php4 .php .phtml .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi 
php_flag engine off
```

Create an  htaccess in your folder an add that to it.

 
The php will not be interpreted but will be shown as plain text

Comment: But if this `file.php` file will be included in other php file  outside from directory, `file.php` will be run.